# Jquery: stop a code from finishing or ignoring the rest of it if a certain condition is set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, break

Can we stop a code from finishing or ignoring the rest of it if a certain condition is set?

For instance,

```
var breakme = false;
if(breakme === true) break;

....
....
bla bla bla the rest of the code
....
...
```

is it possible?

Comment: **Please improve your post.** From what I can see here you'll never get `breakme` to be true. Anyway, if it should happen, then the statement should be a `return;`(or throwing an Error too) and not a `break;`.

Comment: Yes it's possible. This is very basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your if statement is in an function you can use "return false" to break out of the function.

Example:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (true) {
        return false;
    }

    alert("Hey I'm executing other code");
}
```

The alert will never be executed as long as your statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on why you want to do it, but the easiest way to terminate an entire script is to throw an error (assuming your block isn’t wrapped in a `try`):

```
throw new Error();
```

If you meant a function, it’s `return`. Node has a `process.exit()`.